# Find $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2^{n}\left[\log\left(2\right)\right]^{n} \over n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $\mbox{Find}\displaystyle{\quad
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2^{n}\left[\log\left(2\right)\right]^{n} \over n!}}$.

---

Answer is $3$, by the ratio test the series converges. I googled it, but stuck for procedure.

Can you explain it, please ?.

Comment: @Felix Marin, oops, that's not $\mbox{}\displaystyle{\quad
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\left[2^{n}\log\left(2\right)\right]^{n} \over n!}}$, It's given as $\mbox{}\displaystyle{\quad
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2^{n}\left[\log\left(2\right)\right]^{n} \over n!}}$. :)

Comment: Originally, it was written different.

Comment: @Felix Marin, No, that was correct, you can see :) http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2010300/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the exponential series, you find

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{2^{n}\left[\log\left(2\right)\right]^{n} \over n!}=e^{2\ln 2 }-1=2^2-1=3 $$

Answer (score 4):

One may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^x,\quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay You are welcome.